# Powershell to 7z a folder with encryption

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am starting out with Powershell, and it seems fun so far.  Tonight, I am working on a script that compresses a folder with 7z and adds encryption to the new .7z file (see below).

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  

$timestamp = get-date -f yyyyMMdd
$Source = "D:\dbbackup\$timestamp-0300" 
$Target = "D:\backup\$timestamp.7z"

sz a -mx=9 $Target $Source -p1234
```

Ultimately, I need to create an encrypted 7z file out of a folder that is changing every night with the yyyyMMdd, and then followed by a constant number (in this case, yyyyMMdd-0300). With the above script, I can run it, and a new 7z file will be created.  However, the password 1234 will not apply. There is no encryption at all.

If I leave out the `$timestamp` and only run the 7z with the `$source` and `$target`, I can successfully create an encrypted 7z file.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: first result on [google](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples). Have you tried & or iex to run the exe ?

Comment: You might have to pass `-p1234` to Powershell as an `ArgumentList`  see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/arguments-for-remote-commands.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
$sz = ("$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe") 

$timestamp = get-date -f yyyyMMdd
$Source = "D:\dbbackup\$timestamp-0300" 
$Target = "D:\backup\$timestamp.7z"

Start-Process $sz -argumentList "a", "-mx=9", "$Target", "$Source", "-p1234" -Wait
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the suggested answer, but you pointed me to the right direction.  I changed the last line to & $sz "a" "-mx=9" "$Target" "$Source" "-p1234"  and I was able to apply the encryption key to my 7z file.

Comment: Confused me for a minute. Didn't understand that the -p wasn't part of the sample password but was instead a 7-Zip switch. I ended up using a decrypted SecureString, "-p$unencryptedPW" - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just because it cost me some time to pass directories with spaces I am presenting similar one which solves that issue, the below is an example of how to encrypt a .bak files and send encrypted archive into a shared location:

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  

$timestamp = get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd
$Source = "C:\backups ang logs\*.bak"
$Target = "\\192.168.12.345\d\DropBoxFolder\My Daily Backups $timestamp.7z"

sz a -mx=0 -pStrongPassword -mhe=on -m0=lzma2 $Target $Source | Out-Null
```

`m0=lzma2` is the compression algorithm [(more here)](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html)

`-mx=0` for LZMA2 means 64KB dictionary, 32 fastbytes, HC4 matchfinder and BCJ filter
I have used it here as most native .bak files would be compressed already

`mhe=on` enables header encryption (more 7z methods [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm))

`Out-Null` Hides the output instead of sending it down the pipeline or displaying it (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-5.1))